# Installing SteamVR via NixOS?

Tags: steam, nixos

Has anyone used SteamVR with NixOS?

Per the Valve instructions [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/SteamVR-for-Linux), I added the following udev rules to my configuration.nix:

```
services.udev.extraRules = ''
# HTC Vive HID Sensor naming and permissioning
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2c87", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2101", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2000", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1043", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2050", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2011", TAG+="uaccess"
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2012", TAG+="uaccess"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2c87", TAG+="uaccess"
# HTC Camera USB Node
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="114d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8328", TAG+="uaccess"
# HTC Mass Storage Node
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="114d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8200", TAG+="uaccess"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="114d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8a12", TAG+="uaccess"
'';
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libgobject-2.0.so.0, libglib-2.0.so.0, libgio-2.0.so.0, libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0, libpulse.so.0, libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
```

as well as the popup error:

```
 SteamVR failed to initialized for unknown reasons. (Error: Shared IPC Compositor Connect Failed (306))
```

**Other Relevant Steam Output:**

- I get lots of `sh: lsb_release: command not found`.
- I get lots of `sh: pidof: command not found`
- I get a `Initialize() is failed!!!`
- I get a `/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamVR/bin/linux32/vrserver: error while loading shared
- I'm running from the `nixos-unstable` channel.